# How Can I Centralize Content Usage and Approval in a WordPress Multi-Site installation

Tags: php, wordpress, administration

I am working with a non-profit client that runs several charities under one umbrella. A good metaphor would be to think of the United Way (but it's not the United Way).

Can a WordPress multi-site installation do the following:

1. Share content between sites. E.g., if site A has a section called "Advocacy", can that same content also be shown in site B? This would need to include text, photos, etc.
2. How centralized can administration be made? For example, can draft posts from all websites be approved in one location?

I'm sure there are other things I need to ask, but I'm still in the investigation phase.